# coffeescript: why does "str".replace(/ /g, "") give coffeescript compile error?

Tags: compilation, coffeescript

The offending line

```
"str".replace(/ /g, "")
```

gives

```
Error: In orders.js.erb.coffee, Parse error on line 463: Unexpected 'MATH'
    at Object.parseError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/parser.js:466:11)
    at Object.parse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/parser.js:542:22)
    at Object.compile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/coffee-script.js:38:22)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:149:33
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:115:19
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (fs.js:107:5)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:61:17)
    at afterRead (fs.js:878:12)
    at wrapper (fs.js:245:17)
```

Is this a bug in the coffeescript compiler or am I missing something?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[Escape the first whitespace inside of the regexp](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1049)

```
"str".replace(/\ /g, "")
```

compiles just fine.

Comment: It's sad that the coffeescript documentation mentions nothing about needing to escape spaces in regular expressions.